# how count the selected children of a hierarchy

Tags: count, mdx, children

I'm in this situation.
I have a cube that has data aggregated by day.
This cube has a dimension with hierarchy (year-> month-> day).
in this hierarchy are visible every day for the last 4 months.

my problem is counting the days selected, because I need to do calculations based on the days observed (on a pivot).

example:
There are data for the day 11/11/2013 (amount orders), but in the hierarchy I select values from 10.11.2013 to 20.11.2013 ..

how do I calculate (amount orders) / 11?

11 is the number of days 10-20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer at [MDX average fact items count by time dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845426/mdx-average-fact-items-count-by-time-dimension/19855114#19855114).

Having the day count as a measure in the cube would automatically apply all filters etc. without you having to take care of it.

Comment: thanks i have added a measure with DISTINCT COUNT of IDTIME in TIME_TIMENSION. WORKS FINE!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Count() function to calculate the number of members in a set. Your set can consist of a range of dates if you use a colon between start and end date. Something like this:

```
Count({[Date].[Day].&[2013]&[11]&[10] : [Date].[Day].&[2013]&[11]&[20]})
```